# Why is request.FILES not working?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

When I try to use request.Files I get the following error

```
WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Files'
```

heres my views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post




def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.Files or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

        messages.success(request, "Created !!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "not Created !!")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "title": "Create Form"
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_form.html", context)
```

but in the tutorial i'm watching he uses it without a hitch. How Can I fix this?

Comment: `FILES`, not `Files`?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi thanks

Comment: and you don't need to repeat `None`, just `request.POST, request.FILES or None`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi - You should consider making that an answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you spelled wrong, it is `request.FILES` not `request.Files`

```
form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
```

Comment: You should at least explain what you've changed and why it solves the problem.